# Android App / Service to Turn off Blue Tooth programmatically at specified time

Tags: android, service, bluetooth

I'm new to android dev. I've to ask primitive details for which my apologies be accepted first. I intend to develop an android application / service which should let user enter time in hours format (say) and then turn off the bluetooth connection of mobile phone at that specified time. I want to first test application on emulator. I want to know 2 things. Firstly, whether its gona be an application? Or it be a service? Secondly, please help me how to go by this. Bundles of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) is a component of an application, not a standalone entity.
2. You should use [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule an event in future. When it occurs your [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) should get an intent and launch a service, which will turn off the wifi.

Comment: tat is privileged information. can you help me with little code here.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. I just followed a tutorial and got my desired job done.